# Updating Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem populating table from MySQL to another MySQL table
I read it from one table and then it is fine
when a surname like O'Brian 
when I update another table all update exept the O' Brian or any name or surname with the ' in it al through PHP
Ok Here is complete code

```
    $STH2  = $this->run_query("SELECT `member_id`,`first_name`,`last_name` FROM `member_data` WHERE `member_id` = '".$evi."'");

                            $foundme=0;
                            while ($rowtop = $STH2->fetch())
                                            {
                                                $foundme++;

                                                $first_name = $rowtop['first_name'];
                                                $last_name= $rowtop['last_name'];


                                         }

                                 $q = $this->update("

                             UPDATE `users` 
                             SET 
                             `first_name` = '".$first_name."', 
                             `last_name` = '".$last_name."',
```

Comment: Please look into prepared statements and bind variables as this will solve this and a few other potential problems.

Comment: Take a look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) - you'll also solve a security issue your code currently has while you're at it.

Comment: I did try using .utf8_encode($last_name) as well

Comment: @TheWizard that is not what is being suggested. Please actually read the comments.

Comment: utf encoding is NOT going to help. Read and heed the comments about PDO.

Comment: Please have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you use PDO try this :

```
$bdd = /* your database connexion */

$sql = "UPDATE `user` 
        SET `first_name` = :first_name, `last_name` = :last_name
        WHERE `member_id` = 2001;";

$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name);
$req->bindParam(':last_name', $last_name);
$req->execute();
```

If you don't use PDO, the syntax may differ but the logic should be the same just adapt :

- Create the query with some 'param', here `:first_name` and `:last_name`
- Prepare your query
- Bind the param with the actual value, here `$first_name` and `$last_name`
- Then execute the query

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Please note, other providers might not support named parameters.